# How to test an exception was not thrown with Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, error-handling, jestjs

The Jest docs do not demonstrate a way of asserting that no exception was thrown, only that one was.

`expect(() => ...error...).toThrow(error)`

How do I assert if one was **not** thrown?

Comment: If you have an uncaught exception, your tests will fail. Is there a situation where many different type of exceptions can be thrown except one type?

Comment: How would you test that if you needed that kind of test?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can always use the `.not` method, which will be valid if your initial condition is false. It works for every jest test:

```
expect(() => ...error...).not.toThrow(error)
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#not

Comment: I'm wondering if this can handle functions with void return type? I'm getting `Error: expect(received).not.toThrowError() \n Matcher error: received value must be a function \n Received has value: undefined`

Comment: @sbnc.eu It works also for void return type if you wrap it into a function. `expect(() => myvoidreturnfunction()).not.toThrow()`

Answer (score 37):

In my case the function being tested was asynchronous and I needed to do further testing after calling it, so I ended up with this:

```
await expect(
  foo(params),
).resolves.not.toThrowError();

// My other expects...
```